# certificate Error SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am using a ruby/rails application which recieves some information by rest/API from another ruby/rails app.

Second rails app has address like: https://railsapp2.domain.org (This is the authorized url which I am using in my first app)

But I get error when job runs on my first app.

Error is: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

and i believe issue is because of this code in my app:

```
 def self.fetch(url)
   authorized_url = RemoteRequestBuilder.authorize_and_decorate!(url)

   RestClient.get(authorized_url, { accept: :json }) { |response, request, result, &block|
    raise SparcApiError unless response.code == 200

    @response = response
  }

  Yajl::Parser.parse @response
end
```

I looked for some answers and found that I can use verify_ssl: false , but I don't know where to use it. And also how can I make it work using verify_ssl : true.

I also installed certified gem but it does not change anything in output.

i am using centOS7.

**EDIT**

so I did this

```
   RestClient::Resource.new(
   authorized_url,
   :ssl_client_cert  => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("/etc/certs/mycert.pem")),
   :ssl_client_key   =>  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/etc/private/mykey.key")),
   :ssl_ca_file      =>  "/etc/certs/mycert.pem",
   :verify_ssl       =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
   ).get(authorized_url, { accept: :json }) { |response, request, result, &block|
  raise SparcApiError unless response.code == 200

  @response = response
}
```

and now it gives me error wrong number of arguments in get.

| wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
/home/capistrano/opt/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/resource.rb:49:in `get'

so I removed authorized_url argument from get and then it started giving me the error cerificate verification failed.

so I put

```
 :verify_ssl       =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

and Now it's giving me error:  Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#ssltls-support) of Rest-Client gem

```
RestClient::Resource.new(
  'https://example.com',
  :ssl_client_cert  =>  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("cert.pem")),
  :ssl_client_key   =>  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("key.pem"), "passphrase, if any"),
  :ssl_ca_file      =>  "ca_certificate.pem",
  :verify_ssl       =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
).get
```

can be used to specify ca-certificate and verify them. In case you do not want to verify it, modify the `verify-ssl` key to `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

As per the RestClient gem source code for [RestClient.get()](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L65) and [RestClient::Resource.new(...).get](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/resource.rb#L49), both these methods call [Request.execute()](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L66). Therefore your arguments will remain the same except you'll need to pass authorized url to the `.new`'s argument. So your code will become like this:

```
my_client = RestClient::Resource.new(
  authorized_url,
  :ssl_client_cert  =>  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("cert.pem")),
  :ssl_client_key   =>  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("key.pem"), "passphrase, if any"),
  :ssl_ca_file      =>  "ca_certificate.pem",
  :verify_ssl       =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
)

my_client.get({ accept: :json }) { |response, request, result, &block|
    raise SparcApiError unless response.code == 200

    @response = response
  }
```

This way, you can re-use the `my_client` object to send `GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE` requests with same ssl options and url. e.g. `my_client.post(...){...}`

---

**NOTE**:

1. Verifying ssl certificate shouldn't be skipped in production. This should be used in dev/test environment only, otherwise you will be susceptible to the man in the middle attacks.
2. If you trust the CA certificate then you should add it to your host's installed certificates bundle.

Comment: But not that not verifying means that you are open to undetected man-in-the-middle attacks. Thus, providing the appropriate CA certificate is the recommended option for anything but testing-only code.

Comment: how can I parse the response from this code the way I am doing, check my code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with proper usage. You shouldn't pass `authorized_url` again to the `.get` method.

Comment: thanks , it is working now. only issue is why its not working when I enable verify_ssl, I have copied certificate provided by the authority which is a wildcard certificate , I have copied .pem and private key to sepate files and linked it here in code, but it still throws certificate not verified.

Comment: As per your edited code, it show's that your CA certificate is same as your client certificate. Self signed certificate means you created your own CA cert and used it to sign your self generated server certificate. Also, does the authorized url server have a server certificate that is signed by your `my_cert.pem`? If not then you should provide the correct CA certificate in the argument that was used to sign your railsapp2.domain.org.